# How to Make Click event of Button in HorizontalView item in android

Tags: android, adaptor

I have Horizontal View item which have(Image ,name below image,and two button (yes,no) below name)

I want to make click Event Of Yes No Button In Class ..Not In Adaptor when CLick On Button on itemClick is Performing ....Button CLick Is not Performed

i tried Like This Please Tell Me Where I m Doing Wrong

i tried Like This below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListView clicked" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (v.getId() == R.id.yes) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yes  clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.no_btn) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No  clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

in adaptor

```
setClickListeners(holder.btnyes);
 setClickListeners(holder.btnno);

        //Button click Yes

      /* holder.btnyes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    ((HorizontalListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);

                UserProfile u=new UserProfile();

                  data.remove(position);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
            //  new adduser().execute();

            }
        });*/
       holder.btnno.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    ((HorizontalListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);

                /*UserProfile u=new UserProfile();

                  data.remove(position);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();*/
            //  new adduser().execute();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of

```
 setClickListeners(holder.btnyes);
```

try this

```
setOnItemClickListner();
```

Comment: sorry,for the late can you post me the complete code